# Scanner.hasNext() stays to wait for input when it should not

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As title states, I'm trying to check if the Scanner has any input left after the 1st run, but it does not stop if there's nothing left to do but instead stays to wait for more input. What am I doing wrong with the structure?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = "";
        int loop = 0;
        
        while(true) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (loop == 0) sb.append(reader.nextLine() + " ");
            else {
                sb.append(line + " ");
                reset();
            }
            while (true) {
                line = lukija.nextLine() + " ";
                if (line.equals("0 ")) {
                    sb.append(" 0 ");
                    break;
                }
                sb.append(line);
            }

            //
              Rest of the code that calls the different procedures, not needed on this issue as it    
              doesnt use the scanner 
            //

            if (reader.hasNext()) line = reader.nextLine();
            else line = null;
            if (line == null || line.equals("0 ")) break;
            loop++;
        }
    }
```

The code should return false in

```
reader.hasNext()
```

for input like

```
1 500
-1 deadPerson 0 0
2 kidA 0 1
3 kidB 1 0
0
0
```

it should run the code only once as the lonely 0 works as the split. Originally I was able to get past this issue in the code earlier with

```
if (line.equals("0 ")) {
   sb.append(" 0 ");
   break;
```

but as for now the scanner no longer has any imput left and should change to change the

```
String line
```

into null, but instead it stays to wait for more input.

I've tried using try - catch structure, reader.hasNextLine(), reader.next(), without if -structure and checking for null value

I've really starting to run out of ideas as how to solve this, since if I can't use any of the scanner's structures to check if it still has things left in it to determine if it's worth it to run the programm again, then how?

EDIT: Thanks for the help, turns out I was focusing on wrong problem and got it to work as wanted with "small" canges to the loop where the scanner were added into StringBuilder. Did it with adding new boolean variable `endLoop = false` and after finding first 0 reading next word. If it resulted into "0", endloop would be changed into true and loop would be broken in the end of code.

```
    else while (true) {
        line = reader.nextLine() + " ";
        if (line.equals("0 ")) {
            line = reader.next();
            if (line.equals("0")) endLoop = true;
            sb.append(" 0 ");
            break;
        }
        sb.append(line);
    }
```

```
//
rest of the code
//
```

```
    if (endLoop) break;
    loop++;
```

Yes the solution may not be the most effective, but i'm still learning the proper way of coding. Kept the String line against some of the suggestions, but for me it's easier to understand what happends and what gets added to StringBuilder in each loop when debugging.

Comment: "but as for now the scanner no longer has any imput left and should change to change the  `String line` into null" what makes you think so? Scanner doesn't return `null`. Ever. Anyway please note that Scanner is reading from `System.in` which is still opened (meaning it can at some point provide some data). Because of this `hasNext()` can't for sure say that "since now there is no data I will return `false`" because in this precise moment data can be *generated* (user may be in the middle of writing something). So until System.in is closed the `hasNext()` method will never return false.

Comment: If you want to have clear indication that there is no more data to read, consider reading from File.

Comment: Also don't mix `hasNext()` with `nextLine()`. Either use `hasNext` with `next()` or `hasNextLine()` with `nextLine()`.

Comment: BTW `sb.append(line + " ");` we use `StringBuilder` *precisely* to avoid string concatenation. Use `sb.append(line).append(" ");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`System.in` is *usually* an infinite resource. Specifically, it's 'whatever the user types in on the console' (by default) and that **has no end**, hence `.hasNext()` *never* returns `false`. Unless on some OSes they press CTRL+D to indicate end-of-input, which most apps aren't in the habit of requiring, and hence, most users don't know about.

It sounds like you think if the user stops typing in more stuff, that `.hasNext()` should return false. But that's not how it works. `hasNext()` doesn't return `false` because the user *could* type more. The fact that they aren't currently doing that, so what, they might do that later.

There are ways (other than CTRL+D) to have a finite (i.e. eventually `.hasNext()` returns `false` if you've consumed everything) `System.in`: Simply `java -cp . com.foo.MyApp <somefile.txt` will do that. Are you doing that?

Generally if you're using `System.in` is a resource there is some token or sequence that indicates 'we are done now', and you look for that. For example, imagine a system where you type in some command. Instead of waiting for 'input to end' (`.hasNext()` to return `false`), wait for the input token `QUIT` or `EXIT` or some such; the user can end your program by typing QUIT and hitting enter.

There is no way to ask java: Has the user stopped typing for a while?

There are ways to hack that but it's very very complicated - you'd have to start a second thread that runs a timer which is reset every time the user enters something and which quits your application if the timer hits some number you decided means 'no further input is gonna happen from here on out'. I'm not sure it's worth explaining how to do this; it's a real killing a mosquito with a bazooka situation.